# Find all deleted files in a git repositor along with who deleted them

Tags: python, git

I have a project under version control with Git. In this project there is a "grid" of files which are organized like

```
/parts
  /a
    01.src
    02.src
    ...
    90.src
  /b
    01.src
    02.src
    ...
    90.src
  /...
```

(It doesn't matter for the question, but maybe it helps to know that these numbered files are small excisions from a musical score.)

These numbered files are generated by a script, and one part of our work is deleting those files that are not used in the musical score.

Now I would like to retrieve information on *who* deleted each file (as part of our project documentation and workflow). Information retrieval is done from a Python script.

I have a working approach, but that is extremely inefficient because it calls Git as a subprocess for each file in question, which may be far beyond 1.000 times.

What I can do is calling for each file that is missing in the directory tree:

`git log --pretty=format:"%an" --diff-filter=D -- FILENAME`

This gives me the author name of the last and deleting commit affecting the file. This works correctly, but as said I have to spawn a new subprocess for each deleted file.

I can do the same with a for loop on the shell:

`for delfile in $(git log --all --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D | sort -u); do echo $delfile: $( git log --pretty=format:"%an" --diff-filter=D -- $delfile); done`

But this is really slow, which is understandable because it spawns a new git call for every single file (just as if I'd do it from Python).

So the bottom line is: Is there an efficient way to ask Git about

- all files that have been deleted from the repository
  (possibly restricted to a subdirectory)
- along with the author name of the last commit touching each file
  (or actually: The author who deleted the file)

?

Comment: Have you tried using [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/)?

Comment: No, but the problem is not getting Git to run from Python but to find a way to retrieve the information *without* having to launch Git for each file individually (as also my shell solution does).

Comment: You mean you want to process the .git\logs, .git\objects, etc. all by yourself? Seems to me you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Hm, somehow we are talking around each other without really understanding what the other means. I'd suspect that my current solution is reinventing the wheel because I let Git give me a list and then I call Git again for each item in this list. What I need is a list of all deleted files along with the author of the responsible commit. If one could go the other way round it would be nice too: Ask git about all commits that have deleted files and only print the commit author and the deleted-file-names

Answer (score 0):

It seems my last comment brought me on the right track myself:

`git log  --diff-filter='D|R' --pretty=format:'%an' --name-only parts`

gives me the right thing:

`--diff-filter` filters the right commits
`--pretty=format:'%an'` returns only the author
`--name-only` returns a list of deleted files

So as a result I get something like

```
Author-1
deleted-file-1
deleted-file-2

Author-2
deleted-file-3
deleted-file-4

Author-1
deleted-file-5
```

This doesn't give me any more information on the commits, but I don't need that for my use-case. This result can easily be processed from within Python.

(For anybody else landing on this paeg: If you need a similar thing but also want information on the result you can modify the `--pretty=format:'..'` option. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History for a list of items that can be displayed)